# Why is sed removing the greater than symbol

Tags: regex, unix, sed, str-replace

The less-than symbol is removed when I run my `sed` command.

```
a::b<type::value> & d
a::b<ns::type::value>& d
```

```
sed -i 's/[^:]type/changed::type/g'
```

results in

```
a::bchanged::type::value> & d
a::b<ns::type::value>& d
```

I expected to actually get the following:

```
a::b<changed::type::value> & d
a::b<ns::type::value>& d
```

Why is the less-than symbol removed? How can I keep it?

Comment: `<` is a "less than" symbol.

Comment: Or, a "left angle bracket"

Comment: Use `sed -i -E 's/(^|[^:])type/\1changed::type/g'`

Comment: to get the required output you may try this: sed -i 's/<type/<changed::type/g'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol gets removed because it matches `[^:]` "not a colon", as part of the string to be replaced. You can bypass that by capturing it and putting it back:

```
sed -i 's/\([^:]\)type/\1changed::type/g'
```